# Cauchy's residue theorem proof not working

Tags: complex-analysis

I know about a false proof $2\pi i=0$ because $e^{2\pi i}=e^0$. It's false since $e^z$ is not injective, or in other words natural log is multivalued. If I want to prove Cauchy's residue theorem using methods akin to real analysis and taking a definite integral I get $\ln(\gamma(T))-\ln(\gamma(0))$ where T is the time get back where you started in a loop $\gamma$. It seems like this would always be 0 since gamma of T is gamma of zero, as would the specific case of $e^{it}$ for $\frac{1}{z}$ where you get $\ln(e^{2\pi i})-\ln(e^0)$ which is supposedly equal. So why is this $2\pi i$ rather than zero?

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean if you don't tell what integral you're talking about, but I'm afraid  you tried an integral on a path around zero...and logarithm  doesn't behave well there.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'll think about natural log behaviour. The integral is around any closed curve $\gamma$, and I gave $\frac{1}{z}$ as a specific example.

Comment: @DonAntonio isn't a singularity in the middle the point of these contour integrals? Why is that weird, and the logs aren't being evaluated at 0

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\gamma$ contains the origin, as the function is not holomorphic everywhere inside the contour, you may not invoke the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and write

$$\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz\color{red}=F(z_0)-F(z_0)=0$$ where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ and $z_0$ a point on $\gamma$. In particular,

$$\oint_\gamma\frac{dz}z\color{red}=\log1-\log1=0$$ is wrong.

---

By explicit computation, deforming $\gamma$ to a circle,

$$\oint_\gamma\frac{dz}z=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\frac{de^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}=i\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=i2\pi.$$

(Here the FTC holds as the integrand is real and continuous.)

Comment: So basically it's improper?

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn: not at all. There is no limit involved, all integrals are on bounded integrands in bounded domains.

Comment: Ok, I could sort of see how it could be improper but I had a feeling that wouldn't make sense. Why does the FTC fail then?

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn: because its conditions are not fulfilled.

Comment: Why does it need these conditions, and also does this and FTC need the conditions for the same reason?

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn: every theorem needs conditions. Functions have a priori no reason to fulfill the FTC.